# Android studio : Creating a normal xml file in assests folder?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I've been trying to create a normal XML file in Android studio for manual RSS feed but android studio not letting me to create it. I just started using Android studio & migrated from eclipse.

Here's the options for `File`->`New`

[image]

Comment: File -> New -> File  then right click new file Refactor -> Rename

Comment: It's right there, Android Resource File. just add .xml at the end.

Comment: File -> New -> File-> Enter xml file name with extension : textfile.xml

Comment: @Solarnum & prosper : Both works, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I was totally wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, it is simple. You need to put "ordinary" xml file inside "raw" folder and you can create it by clicking `new->file` and setting its name to `rss.xml` for example.

If you dont have raw folder then right-click on `res->new->Android res directory` select resource type to raw and click ok